# How to create DVD from a video file?

Tags: video, dvd

I'm trying to create a DVD image from a `.ts` file but all dvd-maker programs I tried (devede, bombono) output `.mpg` files instead of the desired image with VIDEO_TS, AUDIO_TS folders and `.vob` files inside.

Comment: Ehmmm... Have you tried to create a "Disc copy" on "Brasero"? It will deliver an .iso image file from your DVD in a folder in your hard disk drive. If you are trying to achieve something different please edit your question in order to include the details on what you are trying to do. If Brasero does the work as you wish please let me know in order to add it as an answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your question looks a bit ambiguous as you say explicitly say you are trying to "create dvd from video file" in the title of your question but then you mention that you are "trying to make DVD image from .ts file" and you add that you wish an: "image with VIDEO_TS, AUDIO_TS folders and vobs inside."

Both tasks are related but seems to have different answers.

First of all, if you already have the .ts and the .vob files is that easy as burning them in a DVD inside of a folder called VIDEO_TS (AUDIO_TS is optional).

Now. If you have video files and you wish to create an iso image-file with the DVD files and folders inside of it, your best chance will be the usage of **[DVD Styler](http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/)** which can easily be installed in your system by dropping `sudo apt-get install dvdstyler` in a terminal or via the Software Center.

The process to create a video DVD from your collection of video files is a little bit complicated if this is your first time using DVD Styler, but you will get used to it soon.

Now let's cook a One Video DVD without Menu following the next Recipe.

### The ingredients:

1. Ubuntu, your favorite flavour. I prefer 14.04 LTS
2. A fresh install of DVD Styler
3. One video file
4. Patience.

### Directions:

### 1. Start New Project

Let's start with a Nautilus File Browser opened in the folder where we have the video to be used for this recipe. We'll also open DVD Styler, the scenery may look like this:

[image]

In the first window, DVD Styler will welcome us by asking for the new project specs, it is usually set to our region specs so we need not to change anything in this screen but if you wish you can adjust the video quality in the drop down list having in mind that a bigger bitrate will deliver high quality Videos but it will also reduce the capacity of the DVD.

[image]

When ready, hit the "OK" button after which you'll see the "Select template for DVD menus" dialog as shown in the next screenshot:

---

### 2. Select template

[image]

This recipe is for a Video with No Menu so we'll hit the **"No template"** button in order to continue.

Inside of DVD Styler we'll notice the left sidebar, the project preview to the right and the contents of the DVD at the very bottom with an item called "Menu 1", as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

***IMPORTANT!*** Please don't delete the "Menu 1" item. If you do so you may experience some errors when creating the iso or burning the project to a DVD. We'll simply override the menu in the next steps.

---

### 3. drag and drop our video

Now, let's drag and drop our video in the contents area, just aside the "Menu 1" item.

[image]

---

### 4. Override DVD-Menu

Now let's instruct the project to override the menu from appearing and let's place the "Title 1" item in first instance in order to make the DVD to start playing the video instead of a Menu. Let's hit the menu "DVD" then "Options" after which we'll see the "Properties" dialog. Let's change the "First Play Commands" and set **"jump title 1;"** as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

---

### 5. Override Menu at the end of the DVD

Now, let's double click the "Title 1" item in order to see the "Properties - Title 1" dialog. In that window we'll set the "Post commands:" to **"exit;"** instead of "call last menu;" as shown in the next screenshot:

[image]

Then, hit the **"OK"** button and let's start the oven.

---

### 6. Burn

Go to the "File" menu and choose **"Burn DVD"**, for the creation of a .iso image we'll use the "create iso image" option from the list. The "preview" is optional and will only open the video file after transcoded (so you can un-check this).

[image]

After **choosing the right folder where the .iso image file will be saved**, let's hit the **"Start"** button.

---

### 7.

A progress window will appear, and at the end of the transcoding, the media player will open the preview and once you close that player, you will be asked if you wish to create an iso image of the video. We should hit the "Yes" button, after which a "Generating was successful" message in green will appear. Illustration as follows:

[image]

### [image]

Next simply hit the "Close" button and go to the folder where you requested the iso to be placed. You'll find it right there.

---

### Serving

Remember to serve it cold with a good beverage for the commensal. Oh yeah! You can also burn the iso image with your favorite DVD burner, Brasero is a good choice. :)

If you wish to create a new recipe for more videos, just make sure that each item follows the proper "Post commands" and the DVD Properties (from DVD/Options menu) is set to "First Play Commands" to the menu item. You can also create custom menus with videos, graphics, images, text, etc. It's about to play a while with the options and you will create excellent artworks with ease.

Good luck!

Comment: Would that also work with a H264 encoded file and on Ubuntu 14.04?

Comment: The news section on the Official DVD Styler website (http://www.dvdstyler.org/en/news) seems to have fixed many situations after which this recipe should do what you expect in 14.04, as for the H264 CODEC it should work without a hassle unless you need to install additional codecs. You'll need to check by yourself. Nevertheless, DVD Styler should install all the corresponding resources which may be needed to do its work without a hassle, thus I encourage you to give it a chance and please inform if you succeed. Thank you and Good luck! :D

Comment: It worked with H264. I got some errors: https://gist.github.com/rubo77/f1f189716753c21630a7 - It worked anyway ;)

Comment: Great edit to my answer! Thank you! :D Nevertheless I would not remove the "I prefer 12.04" from the ingredients because of I really prefer 12.04 for now. It would be great if we keep that in order to let other people prefering 12.04 to know that this process will work correctly on 12.04 and add a note that it does work fine in 14.04.

Comment: As for your errors, it seems -to me- standard process. Was the ISO or the DVD created correctly? If so, we can say that's standard process. If not, we should check about the missing dependences in order to correct it.

Comment: I am not sure, I tried to play it with VLC but that didn't work. I will try to burn it tomorrow and check if a DVD player can read it.

Comment: It worked fine on 14.04. I could watch the DVD on an external player. It has no menu, starts right away and stops at the end.

Comment: Good to know @rubo77, so I guess you should try a different player on your computer or install something in order to be able to play that DVD which makes no sense at all but who knows? As for the menu, remember that you can set the "onload" element for the DVD to start playing, and make sure you generated the menu in first instance. They are different than other DVD Authoring tools and they should be created in order to be added as an object, as far as I remember, may have changed since then. Thank you for the feedback and good luck my friend!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will create an ISO image of the DVD.

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo cat /dev/scdX > /home/<user_name>/<file_name>.iso
```

Replace the X with your device lable.

Comment: It is actually the inverse : ake an image from your DVD.